# How to limit the execution of a JavaScript Function triggered after an http-on-modify-request a certain number of times per minute?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

In my Firefox Extension code I am performing a certain (quite heavy computing) functionality after observing AJAX Requests in Facebook. Given that now Facebook relies quite heavily in them and many requests are generated in short second-periods, it is slowing down the performance of the extension! In short, right now I have the following:

```
var httpRequestObserver =
{
  observe: function(subject, topic, data) 
  {
    if (topic == "http-on-modify-request") 
    {
     var httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
     if (httpChannel.URI.spec.search("facebookj.com")!=-1)       
     {
      //setTimeout(function () {my_function();}, 2000);
     }
    }      
  }
};
```

However, now I want to execute `my_function` by limiting the number of times it is executed, say per minute. In other words, I want to simply skip some of the observed HTTP requests if they happen, say, more often than one time per three seconds!

Do I attach a timeout to the observer function? Or do I declare a global counter of observed `http-on-modify-requests` and then call `my_function` only after every third one? Or is there even a better way how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to ignore all requests coming in within 333 milliseconds of the previous request - this will make sure that you never process more than 3 requests per second:

```
var httpRequestObserver =
{
  previousRequest: 0,
  observe: function(subject, topic, data) 
  {
    if (topic == "http-on-modify-request") 
    {
     var httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
     var now = Date.now();
     if (httpChannel.URI.spec.search("facebookj.com")!=-1 &&
         now - this.previousRequest > 333)
     {
      this.previousRequest = now;
      my_function();
     }
    }      
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks Wladimir, I was also thinking along those lines but was not sure if there was a different more comprehensive approach

Comment: @nori: Well, depending on your goal you could allow bursts (multiple requests in quick succession if the previous requests were a while ago). That would mean keeping the time of previous N requests, calculating the average distance between them and then ignoring the current request if it would make the average drop below 333 milliseconds.